# The requested page does not exist.(Not getting satisfyng answer)

Tags: php, yii2

I am creating content management system for my project. I have created models and controllers in protected folder for admin-panel. It is working fine in admin panel but for accessing same controllers and models only changing the view for user-panel but I got the error of page not exist. I search that question here but i am satisfied with answer my issue remains the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you do not provide the problematic code, we cannot help

Comment: Question is unclear, please provide code blocks and the specific problem/error you have so we can help you.

Comment: $model=new Appreciation;
    $model->appriciator==Yii::app()->user->id;
    $data= Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT id FROM {{appreciation}} ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1  ")->queryAll();
    $id1=array_column($data, 'id');
    $id=$id1[0]+1; 
    $model->save(false);        
    $this->redirect(array('updateappriciation', 'id' => $id));

Comment: this is for createappreciation method

Comment: share your directory structure, where is your controller and views inside your project

Comment: For Userpanel:C:\wamp64\www\themes\resale_com\views\modules\appriciation

Comment: and for adminpanel:C:\wamp64\www\protected\views\appriciation             For models;C:\wamp64\www\protected\models                                              For controllers :C:\wamp64\www\protected\controllers                                    Userpanel controllers are kept in:C:\wamp64\www\protected\modules\appriciation

Answer (score 0):

double check your route file and see if the link or the page that is missing is added to your route file,
, 
your route file depends on what mvc framework you are using,

Comment: I have set the links in CustomUrlManager file and.again wrote path in createappriciation method.but its not work

Comment: when I put id as 1 it gave me error of "MainController cannot find the requested view "updateappriciation"." but from db it gave me another id number and the error remains same "
The requested page does not exist."

Comment: Help me on this issue plz. I am doing it from last 2 weeks

Answer (score 0):

Use aliases to achieve this, i suppose both the folders are independent applications.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-aliases.html

Create the alias for "admin-panel" in common/config/aliases.php

```
Yii::setAlias('admin-panel', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/admin-panel');
```

and while rendering the page in user-panel give the view path using alias

```
return $this->render("@admin-panel/views/controllername/file");**
```

**or whatever your folder structure is